# Python function got 2 lists but only changes 1

Tags: python, list, methods, mutability

why does Lista1 get changed but Lista2 doesn't? which methods change directly the list?

```
def altera(L1, L2):
    for elemento in L2:
        L1.append(elemento)
    L2 = L2 + [4]
    L1[1]= 10
    del L2[0]
    return L2[:]

Lista1 = [1, 2, 3]
Lista2 = [1, 2, 3]

Lista3 = altera(Lista1, Lista2)

print(Lista1)
print(Lista2)
print(Lista3)
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: just wanted to know why, already answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L2 = L2 + [4]` This statement create new variable.

If you change this statement to `L2.extend([4])` or `L2 += [4]` then it will change value of `L2` which is `[2, 3, 4]`

printing `id` of `L2` before and after assignment.

```
>>> L2 = [1,2,3]
>>> id(L2)
3072769420L    # ID of L2 
>>> L2 += [4]
>>> id(L2)
3072769420L    # Same ID of L2
>>> L2
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> L2 = L2+[5]
>>> id(L2)
142773548      # New variable which name  is L2
```

Comment: so `L2 = L2 +[4]` != `L2 += [2]` ?

Comment: That's correct. It might be disputable if this is the best of all solutions, but it is as it is.

Comment: `L2 = L2 +[4] != L2 += [4]` : Value of `L2` in both case are same. But in `L2 = L2 + [4]` statement, New `L2` variable created and in `L2 += [4]` statement, Value of `L2` is updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
L2 = L2 + [4]
```

reassigns the address of L2 so it is a different list than was passed in .... thats the easy explanation at least

you can see this by printing `id(L2)` before the assignment and after

if you changed it to

```
L2.append(4)
```

then it would indeed change `Lista2`